# How to print the matching characters in the exact same position between two strings? python

Tags: python, string

I trying to see how many characters stay in the same exact position from the original string to the string printed backwards.

For example:
string1 = d**a**m
string2 = m**a**d
The program would print "1 matching character".  Since "**a**" stayed in the same position in both strings. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried writing code? Loop over the strings simultaneously and compare the characters one by one: `sum([x == y for x, y in zip(s1, s2)])`.

Comment: Can you explain, step by step, how you would do it by hand? Now, try implementing each step in code. Where are you stuck?

Comment: To add to @ggorlen's comment, you could even replace `s2` with a reversal of s1: `sum([x == y for x, y in zip(s1, s1[::-1])])`

Comment: @ggorlen Thankyou for the comment it really helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. It could be made more concise, but here you can clearly see how the count works.

```
string1 = 'dam'

def count_backwards_matches(string):
    stringReverse = string[::-1]
    matches = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i]==stringReverse[i]:
            matches += 1
    return matches

matches = count_backwards_matches(string1)

print( f"{matches} matching character(s)." )
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for I really appreciate it!